# import from node module not working while installed (compile works but compiler gives error)

Tags: syntax, solidity

I'm having a problem importing a file from a module in a solidity contract. Compiling the contract works fine, the red lines just annoy me. I installed the openzeppelin contracts library, used the import in the contract but it keeps giving the compiler error.  (see photo)

[image]

I tried reloading developer window.